# i need to get percentage of error in a column

Tags: sql

i have a table called log
it has few columns including status and time

status has values either ok or 404 error
i need to find On which days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors
i got two queries one to get total requests and other to get errors

```
select count(status) as all ,date(time) as day from log group by day;
```

and this one is for errors

```
select count(status) as error ,date(time) as day from log where status like '404%' group by day;
```

how can i find On which days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ratio, you can use `avg()`:

```
select date(time) as day, avg(case when status like '404%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as error _rate
from log l
group by day;
```